# Sorting a formatted number

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a table with a column for Monthly Rent as shown in the image below. That number is stored in Mongo as a number. Using the value as a number, the table is sortable and it works correctly. My challenge is I'd like to display the value formatted for currency, $900, and yet still be able to sort it as a number. When I format this value as currency, or even put a comma in there 1,200, it sorts it as a string, which I understand, just don't know how to get around it. Any help is appreciated.

[image: sorting]

Here is the code snippet I'm using to generate this table.

```
const rows = leases.map((lease) => {
    const city = lease.city;
    const units = lease.units;
    const { street, monthly_rent, lease_expiration } = units[0];

const columns = [
    {
      dataField: "street",
      text: "Address",
      sort: true,
      sortCaret: (order, column) => {
        if (!order)
          return (
            <span>
              <font color="#E0E0E0">▼▲</font>
            </span>
          );
        else if (order === "asc")
          return (
            <span>
              <font color="black">▲</font>
            </span>
          );
        else if (order === "desc")
          return (
            <span>
              <font color="black">▼</font>
            </span>
          );
        return null;
      },
    },
    {
      dataField: "city",
      text: "City",
      sort: true,
      sortCaret: (order, column) => {
        if (!order)
          return (
            <span>
              <font color="#E0E0E0">▼▲</font>
            </span>
          );
        else if (order === "asc")
          return (
            <span>
              <font color="black">▲</font>
            </span>
          );
        else if (order === "desc")
          return (
            <span>
              <font color="black">▼</font>
            </span>
          );
        return null;
      },
    },
    {
      dataField: "monthly_rent",
      text: "Monthly Rent ($)",
      sort: true,
      sortCaret: (order, column) => {
        if (!order)
          return (
            <span>
              <font color="#E0E0E0">▼▲</font>
            </span>
          );
        else if (order === "asc")
          return (
            <span>
              <font color="black">▲</font>
            </span>
          );
        else if (order === "desc")
          return (
            <span>
              <font color="black">▼</font>
            </span>
          );
        return null;
      },
    },
    {
      dataField: "lease_expiration",
      text: "Lease Expiration",
      sort: true,
      sortCaret: (order, column) => {
        if (!order)
          return (
            <span>
              <font color="#E0E0E0">▼▲</font>
            </span>
          );
        else if (order === "asc")
          return (
            <span>
              <font color="black">▲</font>
            </span>
          );
        else if (order === "desc")
          return (
            <span>
              <font color="black">▼</font>
            </span>
          );
        return null;
      },
    },
  ];
return (
    <React.Fragment>
      <div>
        <h1>Leases</h1>
      </div>
      <div>
        {
          <BootstrapTable
            keyField="street"
            columns={columns}
            data={rows}
            hover
            rowEvents={tableRowEvents}
            bordered={false}
            defaultSorted={defaultSorted}
            rowStyle={rowStyle}
          />
        }
      </div>

      <li></li>
    </React.Fragment>
  );
```

Comment: Assuming you are using React Bootstrap Tables you can look at this https://github.com/TanStack/react-table/issues/315. Essentially what you want to do is create your own customSort method that takes in the value before you pass it the $ sign.

Comment: @justanotherguy Thanks for that link. I'll tinker around with a custom sort and see what I can come up with.